# JQuery Responsive Menu Full width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using a pre-written responsive menu.

http://responsivemobilemenu.com/en/

It's fairly easy to work with but I cannot get the menu to be 100% wide. I have it fixed to the top of my page to scroll with the user. The code for the menu is in a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/uvd1hfrx/

It is in the desktop version that it is not going 100% width so you will have to resize the result part on the fiddle.

I've tried adding `width: 100%` to various parts of the CSS, but nothing has resized it.

Could someone help me figure out how to make this menu as wide as the users screen?

Full code:

HTML:

```
 <div class="rmm" data-menu-style = "graphite">
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href='#about-me'>About me</a></li>
                <li><a href='#gallery'>Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href='#blog'>Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href='#links'>Links</a></li>
                <li><a href='#sitemap'>Sitemap</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </div
```

CSS:

```
/*

Responsive Mobile Menu v1.0
Plugin URI: responsivemobilemenu.com

Author: Sergio Vitov
Author URI: http://xmacros.com

License: CC BY 3.0 http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/

*/

.rmm {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:100%!important;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0 auto !important;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:19px !important;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
.rmm * {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent !important;
    font-family:Arial;
}
.rmm a {
    color:#ebebeb;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.rmm .rmm-main-list, .rmm .rmm-main-list li {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.rmm ul {
    display:block;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin:0 auto !important;
    overflow:hidden;
    list-style:none;
}
.rmm .rmm-main-list li {
    display:inline;
    padding:padding:0px;
    margin:0px !important;
}
.rmm-toggled {
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 auto !important;
}
.rmm-button:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.rmm .rmm-toggled ul {
    display:none;
    margin:0px !important;
    padding:0px !important;
}
.rmm .rmm-toggled ul li {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto !important;
}




/* GRAPHITE STYLE */
.rmm.graphite, .rmm.graphite {
        width: 100%;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-main-list li a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:8px 30px 8px 30px;
    margin:0px -3px 0px -3px;
    font-size:15px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #333333;
    background-color:#444444;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-main-list li a:hover {
    background-image:url('');
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#555555;
    min-height:36px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled-controls {
    display:block;
    height:36px;
    color:white;
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled-title {
    position:relative;
    top:9px;
    left:15px;
    font-size:16px;
    color:white;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px black;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-button {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:15px;
    top:8px;
}

.rmm.graphite .rmm-button span {
    display:block;
    margin-top:4px;
    height:2px;
    background:white;
    width:24px;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled ul li a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#555555;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #333333;
    border-top:1px solid #777777;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #333333;
}
.rmm.graphite .rmm-toggled ul li a:active {
    background-color:#444444;
    border-bottom:1px solid #444444;
    border-top:1px solid #444444;
}
```

JQuery:

```
/*

Responsive Mobile Menu v1.0
Plugin URI: responsivemobilemenu.com

Author: Sergio Vitov
Author URI: http://xmacros.com

License: CC BY 3.0 http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/

*/

function responsiveMobileMenu() {   
        $('.rmm').each(function() {



            $(this).children('ul').addClass('rmm-main-list');   // mark main menu list


            var $style = $(this).attr('data-menu-style');   // get menu style
                if ( typeof $style == 'undefined' ||  $style == false )
                    {
                        $(this).addClass('graphite'); // set graphite style if style is not defined
                    }
                else {
                        $(this).addClass($style);
                    }


            /*  width of menu list (non-toggled) */

            var $width = 0;
                $(this).find('ul li').each(function() {
                    $width += $(this).outerWidth();
                });

            // if modern browser

            if ($.support.leadingWhitespace) {
                $(this).css('max-width' , $width*1.05+'px');
            }
            // 
            else {
                $(this).css('width' , $width*1.05+'px');
            }

        });
}
function getMobileMenu() {

    /*  build toggled dropdown menu list */

    $('.rmm').each(function() { 
                var menutitle = $(this).attr("data-menu-title");
                if ( menutitle == "" ) {
                    menutitle = "Menu";
                }
                else if ( menutitle == undefined ) {
                    menutitle = "Menu";
                }
                var $menulist = $(this).children('.rmm-main-list').html();
                var $menucontrols ="<div class='rmm-toggled-controls'><div class='rmm-toggled-title'>" + menutitle + "</div><div class='rmm-button'><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span></div></div>";
                $(this).prepend("<div class='rmm-toggled rmm-closed'>"+$menucontrols+"<ul>"+$menulist+"</ul></div>");

        });
}

function adaptMenu() {

    /*  toggle menu on resize */

    $('.rmm').each(function() {
            var $width = $(this).css('max-width');
            $width = $width.replace('px', ''); 
            if ( $(this).parent().width() < $width*1.05 ) {
                $(this).children('.rmm-main-list').hide(0);
                $(this).children('.rmm-toggled').show(0);
            }
            else {
                $(this).children('.rmm-main-list').show(0);
                $(this).children('.rmm-toggled').hide(0);
            }
        });

}

$(function() {

     responsiveMobileMenu();
     getMobileMenu();
     adaptMenu();

     /* slide down mobile menu on click */

     $('.rmm-toggled, .rmm-toggled .rmm-button').click(function(){
        if ( $(this).is(".rmm-closed")) {
             $(this).find('ul').stop().show(300);
             $(this).removeClass("rmm-closed");
        }
        else {
            $(this).find('ul').stop().hide(300);
             $(this).addClass("rmm-closed");
        }

    }); 

});
    /*  hide mobile menu on resize */
$(window).resize(function() {
    adaptMenu();
});
```

Screenshot of what my browser shows:

[image]

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: No, but I have considered it.

Comment: I would advise you to use it, unless there is some specification that needs to be met.

Comment: Personal site. Just trying to work with a responsive layout for once.

Comment: I would definitely recommend bootstrap, there are plenty of tools that will generate grids for you and layouts - http://www.layoutit.com/build and for grids http://shoelace.io/ Its a responsive framework, so it will look good on mobile devices.

Comment: I did some looking at those links. I like how that works. I believe I am going to give bootstrap a try.

Answer (score 1):

OK first of all get rid of the margins/paddings in html and body

```
html,body{
  width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;
}
```

then add some width to li>a elements

```
.rmm .rmm-main-list li a{
  width:16.7%; /*(100/6 menus %)*/
}
```

Thats a start and lot of work suggest bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the Javascript provided, there are a couple places that are setting the `max-width` for the `.rmm` class.

If you comment out:

```
// if modern browser

if ($.support.leadingWhitespace) {
    $(this).css('max-width' , $width*1.05+'px');
} 
else {
    $(this).css('width' , $width*1.05+'px');
}
```

in `responsiveMobileMenu()`, this will allow your current nav to be centre.

After that, set `background-color: #444444` in `.rmm` and you should have something similar to what you desire.

As some others have suggested, I also highly recommend using Bootstrap if you have nothing tying you down to this library.